# Evolutions generating an incorrect 1.SQL file when the schema is different from "public"

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

I specifie a schema on all my classes with annotation @Table
Ex : @Table(name = "table_1", schema = "my_schema")

Evolutions creating a 1.sql file with errors. Name of indexes and constraints contains **a dot**.
Ex: create index ix_my_schema.table_1 on my_schema.table_1 (column_id);

I searched a solution for solve this without result.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've raised an issue, it will be fixed in 4.0.5
https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/141

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aitor,

The ticket [141](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/141) of project "avaje-ebeanorm" fix the problem. However they did not version 4.0.5, the first version with the fix is 4.1.0.

For information, the last version of playframework, that is now 2.3.4, have version 3.4.1 of "avaje-ebeanorm". The problem is not resolved in play.

So add the following line in the file build.sbt (or Build.scala) to solve the problem :

```
"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.1.0"
```